# Capistrano: difference between `run` and `sudo`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano

I'm following [#335 Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments) . In the `deploy.rb`,

```
%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
desc "#{command} unicorn server"
task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
  run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
end
```

end

When I run `cap deploy:start`, I get `sh: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: Permission denied`. But if I change run to sudo: `sudo "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"`, I get `sudo: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: command not found`
.

So does the command really not exist, or `sudo` and `run` are different from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting permission denied because a normal user is barred from being inside /etc/init.d/

You are getting command not found because the application is likely incorrect or not set. Basically, does /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname exist? probably not.

You should not be changing run to sudo anyway, you should be using run "#{sudo} ..." or run "#{try_sudo} ... " anyway.